# Android move ImageView to a specific pixel color

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, translate-animation

I made a treasure map in photoshop and I made a transparent image with coloured hotspots to put over the treasure map so I can make it clickable.

When I click on the colored dots (that are invisible), Android detects the color clicked and does the appropriate methods, just as asked.

Now I have an imageview, that would be my player, and each day I want it to move to another colored hotspot on the map (each hotspot represents a day of the week).

I have this code, but the position is way off:

```
private void moveToColor(ImageView iv, int toColor) {

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.hotspots);   
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    bm.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    for (int ix = 0; ix < width; ++ix) {
        for (int iy = 0; iy < height; ++iy) {   
            if (toColor == bm.getPixel(ix, iy)) {
                iv.animate().translationX((float)ix);
                iv.animate().translationY((float)iy);
                return;
            }
        }
    }       
 }
```

sometimes it will move the imageview close to the toColor, and other times it is completely off or not even on the map.

Any pointers on how I could do this. I tried it with a buffer copypixelstobuffer, but I didn't understand very well how that works. Because above is quite slow..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is off, read the description of the `translationX` property carefully: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:translationX

*"This value is added post-layout to the left property of the view"*

It's *relative* to the left of the view, i.e. it's displacement, not absolute position.
Instead, use

```
iv.animate().x((float)ix);
```

and it's twin brother [.y()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#y%28float%29)

Comment: I tried that but it does exactly the same. And overall it's really slow, I see a white screen for about 2-3 seconds before the treasure map with the player is loaded. I hope to find a more efficient way to do this!

Comment: well, the slowness might be due to animation -- do you need to animate it?

Comment: As for x() positioning -- there's no way it does exactly the same as translateX() :) But I'm guessing it might still be off because your image's pixel position is in image's coordinates, while x() is in screen pixel coords. Those two are not equal -- image may be scaled.

Also, to avoid animation, use `iv.setX()`

Comment: setX and setY do resolve the white screen issue.. I do have some trouble with the difference in pixel coordinates, I imagine it is something like that but I have no idea how to get the correct ones...

Comment: Either don't scale the image when displaying in `ImageView`, or use `ImageView.getScaleX/Y()` to get the screen pixel / image pixel ratio and calculate accordingly.

Also, I assume you do account for the image width? `setX()` positions the view by it's *left* edge. So you need to subtract the view's width if you want to put view's center on the spot instead.

Comment: My imageview is loaded through XML. In the layoutfile i specify a drawable. When would i call getscalex/y? Because I call it in onResume() and it returns 1. So either it isn't scaled, which I doubt, or It is called before it is drawn. But I can't find when the imageview is done loading. And i'm a bit confused abou this: "So you need to subtract the view's width if you want to put view's center on the spot instead". I don't want to center it but put it right on the x and y, do I still have to substract the width? I'm still a newbe, so some things are still unclear ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry I meant "half the width". The `setX/Y()` position view's top left corner. So if you want to position view's center instead -- you need to subtract half its width from x and half its height from y.

Scale in `onResume()` should be ok, so I guess it's not scaled. Is the position somehat close to what's expected or just plain wrong?

Comment: it depends on the color, on some colors it's quite close and others it can't find it and the imageview disappears from the screen or really far from the coloured dot, even though I used the cleanest rgb color values to match with Color.RED, Color.BLUE etc. Really can't seem to find out what is going wrong!

Comment: Do you have debug outputs set up? Put some `Log.d()` calls to monitor which coordinates you get from the found pixels -- and compare them with what is really in the picture (like, actually look at the positions in Photoshop/Gimp), maybe use a really simple pic, plain white with the transparent pixels thrown in. That way you'll see whether it's a problem with looking up pixels by color or its it some kind of coordinate conversion thing we're missing.

Comment: So it does have sthg to do with the scaling :) as you said, I only still don't get the entire logic behind it...

Comment: Let's have some debugs thrown in, stuff will probably get clear right away.

Comment: I put what I did in the answer above. I scaled the bitmap to the screen size and then search for the pixels. The player moves close to the dot now, but it is still off like a few pixels. F.e. today it has to move to a certain dot. In Photoshop the pixel coordinates for the bottom of the circle are x=123.50 and y=255 but the pixel coordinates to the first presence of the color is x=88 and y=218. And that is where the player is moved to. But I don't know what this difference represents...

Answer (score 0):

I actually found that if I change

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.hotspots);   
int width = bm.getWidth();
int height = bm.getHeight();
```

to this:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hotspots);

bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,size.x, size.y, true);
int width = bm.getWidth();
int height = bm.getHeight();
```

where size.x and size.y come from

```
display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
```

Then the position is not that far off. It is still not completely where I want it, the player is positioned on the bottom of the dot, but at least it is a step closer.